# Zend Framework 1 Db Multiple where statements

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework

Having following variable `$select` where all necessary configurations are made and works fine. There is task for filtering data on same table like following:

For example table `values` with fields:

- id    object_type object_value
- 1-----------8------------1
- 1-----------5------------300
- 2-----------8------------0
- 2-----------5------------500
- 3-----------8------------1
- 3-----------5------------400
- 4-----------8------------1
- 4-----------2------------10
  ...

Values must be sorted like following:

- When object_type = 8 chose only object_value = 1
- AND
- When object_type = 5 chose only object_value >= 400 For example.

Tried using **Zend_Db_select**`union()` but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas will be very helpfull. Also with `joins` doesn't seem to be an option.Couldn't implement `case`.

**Update**
Applying query should sort data and output :

- id    object_type object_value
- 3-----------8------------1
- 3-----------5------------400

**Explanation**
For example id=1 has 2 rows

- object_type=8
- object_value=1

*AND*

- object_type=5
- object_value=300

Query checks if id with number when object_type = 8 the object_value must be = 1 and when object_type=5 then object_value must be >= 400 so in following case id with number 1 and it's values won't be displayed. Only id with number 3 matched searched query. Hope a little explanation made thinks clear if not i will add later experimental values on concrete objects.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve. 

You want to do a filtered select (showing object_type 8 and object_type 5)? Or you have some parameter to give into your query that let you choose if you want to see object_type = 8 or object_type = 5?

Comment: @Gounemond **Updated** How output should look. Hope thinks become more clear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zend-framework DB: OR instead of AND operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536807/zend-framework-db-or-instead-of-and-operator)

Comment: @Niko no, here is a different task.

Comment: @Igor Could you then try to explain a bit better what you want to achieve? For example, why is there only one row with object_type 8 in your example result?

Comment: @Niko check **Explanation** part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL speaking, what you want is something like this:

```
select a.*, b.*  
from MyTable a
join MyTable b on b.id = a.id
where a.object_type = 8 and a.object_value = 1
and b.object_type = 5 and b.object_value >= 400
```

If you want to achieve a result like this one, you just need to get a good where condition, plus a join condition.

```
//your program

$select = $this->_table->select()
               ->from(array('a' => 'MyTable'),
               ->joinLeft(array('b' => 'MyTable'), 'b.id = a.id', array())

$_where = array()
$_where[] = array('object_type= ' . "8", 'object_value = '. "1");
$_where[] = array('object_type= ' . "5", 'object_value >= '. "400");

// you can do a loop after the first element if 
// you have more conditions to put in OR
$select->where($_where[0]);
$select->orWhere($_where[1]);

//...
```

or, if you're doing an update

```
 _dbTable->update($_data, $_where);
```

(Put in $_data whatever you're going to update)
It may be nice to add an

```
$select->order(...);
```

depending on what you want to do!

Comment: I post in `Update` what output should be based on query.

Comment: So, instead of $_where and $_where2, just declare $_where = array(); $_where[] = //first condition;  $_where[] = //second condition. Then ->update($_data, $_where); (on $_data you will put columns to modify and new values). Check updated answer!

Comment: check `Update` block part in my question.

Comment: I understood now, you want to output a couple with the same ID, that respect both conditions on type - value. Am I right?

Comment: Yes.Already found solution using joins by setting different alias. Checked your answer and is similar to what i have done.